# Inertial frame: Sun earth and moon

Tags: inertial-frames

From the perspective of sun, is the moon orbiting the earth considered a single inertial frame or are moon and earth separate inertial frames?

Or am I missing something completely fundamental?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any frame of references where there are fictitious forces in play is not an inertial frame. and i don't understand by what you mean "...is it a separate entity?" and no, the earth+moon frame cannot be considered an inertial frame because they are moving about the sun.
Can you please rephrase your question?

Comment: Although my question was not clear, thanks, you have answered my question.